# How string is stored in memory

Tags: ruby

I am stuck with a problem .Unable to understand how actually string is stored in ruby

In the first case if a change a character in first object it is reflecting in the second object. I understand due to same object_id

```
 person1 = "tim"
 => "tim" 
 person1.object_id
 => 9194620  
 person2 = person1
 => "tim"  
 person2.object_id
 => 9194620  
 person1[0] = "j"
 => "j"  
 person1
 => "jim"  
 person1.object_id
 => 9194620  
 person2
 => "jim" 
  person2.object_id
 => 9194620
```

In the second case if first object changes so it doesn't reflect on second object due to different object id.

```
  person1 = "jim"
 => "jim"   
  person2 = person1
 => "jim"   
  person1 = "tim"
 => "tim"   
  person1
 => "tim"   
   person2
 => "jim"
```

My question is how it is internally working in memory,Why object_id doesn't change in first case where as in second case it changes?

Comment: `"jim"  = "jim"` isn't valid Ruby syntax

Comment: sorry that was my mistake .I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you assigned a second variable to **the same object** in memory and then **mutated it**:

```
person1 = "tim"
person2 = person1
person1[0] = "j"
```

`person1` and `person2` are still the exact same object in memory, so:

```
person2 == "jim"
```

---

In the second case, you **reassigned** the variable, which sets it to a **different object** in memory:

```
person1 = "tim"
```

`person2` is still `"jim"`, because you have not mutated the object nor reassigned the variable.

Comment: I also know this thing. My question was how it is implemented in memory .According to that tell me how is it changing in memory

Comment: @user6551529 think of a table which maps variables to object ids.

Comment: Can you please illustrate with diagram or something

Comment: @TomLord the first sentence in your answer seems a bit misleading to me. You can make a shallow copy of an object (e.g. via `dup`), but I don't think that you can shallow copy a variable.

Comment: @user6551529 In your original post, you were showing the `object_id` each step of the way. That's all you need to know. When you **reassign** the variable (`person1 = "tim"`), it's creating a new object (a string, `"tim"`) which has a new location in memory - and therefore a new `object_id`.

Comment: In contrast, when you **mutate** an object (`person1[0] = "j"`), this is still the same physical object in memory - so the `object_id` does not change.